# Overriding Margin Collapse

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with 4 child elements. Each child has a 5px margin on the bottom. I can't seem to add a larger `margin-top` to the last child (or equivalently, a larger `margin-bottom` to the preceding child). Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89b504xn/4/).

I've tried adding a top border and top padding to the last child, as well as changing the overflow settings of the container with no luck. Any tips?

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#blurb {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="greeting">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="subtitle">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="blurb">
    content (top margin doesn't change!)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The selector `#header div` is more specific than the selector `#blurb`.

To be more precise, the selector `#header div` has a [specificity calculation](http://specificity.keegan.st/) of `0, 1, 0, 1`, whereas the selector `#blurb` is `0, 1, 0, 0`.

You need to increase the specificity of the selector `#blurb` if you want it to override the other styling.

For instance: [**(updated example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/m192mnv5/)

```
#header div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
div#blurb {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The selector `#header #blurb` would work as well.

```
#header #blurb {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

For what it's worth, you can also use the `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` pseudo-classes to select the last element:

```
#header div:last-of-type {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set some style to the last child use the [last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector:

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 0 0 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#header div:last-child {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="greeting">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="subtitle">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="blurb">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```